# ERROR H14 I can't log in to my nightscout url which im using for glucose readings

Tags: ios, iphone, mongodb, heroku

I cant log in to my nightscout url which im using for glucose readings, it says "Application error, check your logs for details, you can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs--tail.
Please will someone help me :/

Thank you!!! :)

I restarted dynos and thats all I did but still didnt work... :/